# How can i apply pivoting on multiple (my case 3) values?

Tags: t-sql

I have a sample data as follows.

[image: data]

I want to apply pivoting to it such that the data looks like this.

[image: output]

What I have done is as follows (all manually done, so not sharing code, actual code has more fields and is irrelevant to question)

1st step: Declare and set query1 to Pivot the table on [Year] for [IN/OUT] values

[image]

2nd Step : Declare and set query2 to Pivot the table on [Year] for [status]

[image]

3rd Step : Declare and set query3 to pivot the table on [Year] for [Comment]

[image]

4th Step : Declare a string in which i combine query1 query2 and query3 using join statement on ID. On executing this query i get the output as i expect. (2nd image shared.)

I reckon it could be done using UNION instead of JOIN and also without pivoting.

It will be very helpful if you could give me a best possible approach to achieve my requirement.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you could have more than three years, so I would make it a dynamically generated SQL.

```
/*Setup Data */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable
GO
SELECT
    * INTO tmptable
FROM (VALUES(2016, 1150, NULL, 'CALCULATED', 'IN')
, (2017, 1150, 'Zum Verkauf', 'MANUAL', 'OUT')
, (2018, 1150, 'Zum Verkauf', 'MANUAL', 'IN')
, (2019, 1150, 'Zum Verkauf', 'MANUAL', 'OUT')
) a (YEAR, ID, COMMENT, STATUS, "IN/OUT")


GO

/*Start Solution */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmpyear
GO
/* Select which columns are immutable, in you case ID */
DECLARE @IDCols VARCHAR(100) = 'ID'
/* Select which columns to Pivot, as a list*/
DECLARE @PivotCols VARCHAR(100) = 'COMMENT,STATUS,IN/OUT'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

/* Find out how many years are in the data */
SELECT DISTINCT
    CAST(year AS VARCHAR(100)) [year] INTO #tmpyear
FROM tmptable t

/* Build the query */
SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' + @IDCols + ', '
SELECT
@SQL=@SQL+STRING_AGG(CAST( 'max(iif( [year]='+t.[year]+',['+c.[value]+'],''''))'
+'['+ c.[value]+' for '+ T.[year]+']' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),',')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.[value],T.[year])
FROM #tmpyear t
CROSS JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@PivotCols,',') c

SET @SQL = @SQL + 'FROM tmptable group by ' + @IDCols
EXEC (@SQL)
```

This generates this query:

```
SELECT
    id
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2016, [COMMENT], '')) [COMMENT for 2016]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2017, [COMMENT], '')) [COMMENT for 2017]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2018, [COMMENT], '')) [COMMENT for 2018]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2019, [COMMENT], '')) [COMMENT for 2019]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2016, [IN/OUT], '')) [IN/OUT for 2016]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2017, [IN/OUT], '')) [IN/OUT for 2017]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2018, [IN/OUT], '')) [IN/OUT for 2018]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2019, [IN/OUT], '')) [IN/OUT for 2019]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2016, [STATUS], '')) [STATUS for 2016]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2017, [STATUS], '')) [STATUS for 2017]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2018, [STATUS], '')) [STATUS for 2018]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2019, [STATUS], '')) [STATUS for 2019]
FROM tmptable
GROUP BY id
```

If I add data for more years,

```
SELECT
    * INTO tmptable
FROM (VALUES(2016, 1150, NULL, 'CALCULATED', 'IN')
, (2017, 1150, 'Zum Verkauf', 'MANUAL', 'OUT')
, (2018, 1150, 'Zum Verkauf', 'MANUAL', 'IN')
, (2019, 1150, 'Zum Verkauf', 'MANUAL', 'OUT')
, (2020, 1150, 'Zum Verkauf', 'MANUAL', 'IN')
, (2021, 1150, 'Zum Verkauf', 'MANUAL', 'OUT')
, (2022, 1150, NULL, 'MANUAL', 'IN')
, (2023, 1150, 'Zum Verkauf', 'MANUAL', 'OUT')
) a (YEAR, ID, COMMENT, STATUS, "IN/OUT")
```

I get this query:

```
SELECT
    id
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2016, [COMMENT], '')) [COMMENT for 2016]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2017, [COMMENT], '')) [COMMENT for 2017]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2018, [COMMENT], '')) [COMMENT for 2018]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2019, [COMMENT], '')) [COMMENT for 2019]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2020, [COMMENT], '')) [COMMENT for 2020]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2021, [COMMENT], '')) [COMMENT for 2021]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2022, [COMMENT], '')) [COMMENT for 2022]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2023, [COMMENT], '')) [COMMENT for 2023]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2016, [IN/OUT], '')) [IN/OUT for 2016]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2017, [IN/OUT], '')) [IN/OUT for 2017]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2018, [IN/OUT], '')) [IN/OUT for 2018]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2019, [IN/OUT], '')) [IN/OUT for 2019]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2020, [IN/OUT], '')) [IN/OUT for 2020]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2021, [IN/OUT], '')) [IN/OUT for 2021]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2022, [IN/OUT], '')) [IN/OUT for 2022]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2023, [IN/OUT], '')) [IN/OUT for 2023]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2016, [STATUS], '')) [STATUS for 2016]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2017, [STATUS], '')) [STATUS for 2017]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2018, [STATUS], '')) [STATUS for 2018]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2019, [STATUS], '')) [STATUS for 2019]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2020, [STATUS], '')) [STATUS for 2020]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2021, [STATUS], '')) [STATUS for 2021]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2022, [STATUS], '')) [STATUS for 2022]
   ,MAX(IIF([year] = 2023, [STATUS], '')) [STATUS for 2023]
FROM tmptable
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Søren Kongstad, about there being more than 3 years in the table, yes, there will  always be more data in the table,but my requirement is to display the data for last 3 years (including the current). Having said that, this code should work fine for me, i just need to add a where condition in your query. I'll accept the answer after testing.